# How to define extra fields when creating super user in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have this in my `models.py`:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, name, password=None):

        """

        Creates and saves a User with the given name and password.

        """

        if not name:

            raise ValueError('A user must have a name.')



        user = self.model()

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user



    def create_staffuser(self, name, password):

        """

        Creates and saves a staff user with the given name and password.

        """

        user = self.create_user(

            name,

            password=password,

        )

        user.staff = True

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user



    def create_superuser(self, name, password, id):

        """

        Creates and saves a superuser with the given name and password.

        """

        user = self.create_user(

            name,

            id,

            password=password,

        )

        user.staff = True

        user.admin = True

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

The reason I added the field `id` in my `create_superuser` -method is that it is a required field in my model and I thought I need to include it also when running `python manage.py createsuperuser`. My problem is that I don't know how to customize the super user creation. With this I always get the error `TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`. I also tried to remove the id from the function. The process goes through without errors then, but I can't log in to the admin site, it says the username or password are not correct.
I have this in my `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm


User = get_user_model()


# Remove Group Model from admin. We're not using it.

admin.site.unregister(Group)


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    # The forms to add and change user instances

    form = UserAdminChangeForm

    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm



    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.

    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin

    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.

    list_display = ['name', 'admin']

    list_filter = ['admin']

    fieldsets = (

        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'password')}),

        ('Personal info', {'fields': ()}),

        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin',)}),

    )

    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin

    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.

    add_fieldsets = (

        (None, {

            'classes': ('wide',),

            'fields': ('name', 'password1', 'password2')}

        ),

    )

    search_fields = ['name']

    ordering = ['name']

    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Do I need to modify the `admin.py` -file to make this work or is there some other obvious reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: I am not sure why the error occurs but if you add an id field to your user model, it will also be included for the superuser when you create it. Therefore, you do not need to define the id field to the superuser.

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu In my case, the id is not automatically set, it is a manual id that comes outside. I do not need it for the superuser which is just for testing, but I assume the superuser was not saved to the db because the id was missing. That's why I tried to include it when creating the superuser.

Comment: Can I see your base user model? I may have an answer for you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, it is really bad practice to give id value manually. the id should be auto-generated. But if you really want to get id as a function parameter, then you need to override the Django command to create a superuser.

You can read the details for the custom Django admin command here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/